# Unable to send email from SMTP

Tags: .net, email, .net-core, smtp

I am sending an email through the smtp of the company it has no credentials only port 25 but i keep getting this error `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.`, note that i tried to send the email from the hotmail server and it worked (host: smtp.live.com, port 587 and my email credentials)

this is my code:

```
 public static void SendEmail(EmailObject email)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = email.Host;
        smtp.EnableSsl = false; // I Tried to set it true as well
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; // i tried to remove it
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.Password))
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email.Username, email.Password);
        if (email.Port != 0)
            smtp.Port = email.Port;
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.Subject = email.Subject;
        if (email.Attachments != null)
        {
            foreach (EmailAttachment emailAttachment in email.Attachments)
            {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(emailAttachment.AttachmentStream, emailAttachment.AttachmentName, emailAttachment.ContentType);
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
        }
        System.Net.Mail.MailAddress mailAddress = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email.MailAddress, email.DisplayName);
        mailMessage.From = mailAddress;
        foreach (var address in email.Recepients.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            mailMessage.To.Add(address);
        }
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.Body = email.Body.ToString();
        smtp.Send(mailMessage);
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you have issues with the connection between where you are trying to send this email from and the SMTP server of your company. Can you verify outside of your code that you have a connection to the SMTP? And try to double check the connection information for the SMTP.

Comment: @KristianBarrett i have a successful telnet with the smtp server

Comment: Ok so the next thing I would do was to strip down the code to the bare minimums. Just hardcode everything and just send a simple email with a title in it. This way you can make sure that the code can connect to the server. When that is done you can try to build your changes into the more complex code above.